# Using Hibernate Search 6 - How to prevent automatic indexing for a specific entity?

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-search

We would like to handle the indexing ourselves for one of our Hibernate Search entities.

Is it possible to disable auto indexing within Hibernate Search 6 for a specific entity?  Similar to the older Hibernate Search global setting: hibernate.search.indexing_strategy = manual

I've searched through the documentation but haven't seen this mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`hibernate.search.indexing_strategy = manual` was for all entity types, not for a specific one.

The feature you're looking for has already been filed as [HSEARCH-168](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HSEARCH-168), and is currently planned for Hibernate Search 6.2.

In the meantime, I think the best you can do would be to rely on a hack. It won't be as efficient as what we envision for [HSEARCH-168](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HSEARCH-168), but it's a start:

- Implement a [RoutingBridge](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en-US/html_single/#mapper-orm-bridge-routingkeybridge) which, based on a switch, will either disable indexing completely (both adding and removing the entity from the index) or behave normally as if there was no routing bridge:

  ```java
  public class ManualIndexingRoutingBinder implements RoutingBinder {

      private static volatile boolean indexingEnabled = false;

      public static synchronized void withIndexingEnabled(Runnable runnable) {
          indexingEnabled = true;
          try {
              runnable.run();
          }
          finally {
              indexingEnabled = false;
          }
      }

      @Override
      public void bind(RoutingBindingContext context) { 
          context.dependencies() 
                  .useRootOnly();

          context.bridge( 
                  Book.class, 
                  new Bridge() 
          );
      }

      public static class Bridge implements RoutingBridge<Book> { 
          @Override
          public void route(DocumentRoutes routes, Object entityIdentifier, Book indexedEntity, 
                  RoutingBridgeRouteContext context) {
              if ( indexingEnabled ) { 
                  routes.addRoute();
              }
              else {
                  routes.notIndexed(); 
              }
          }

          @Override
          public void previousRoutes(DocumentRoutes routes, Object entityIdentifier, Book indexedEntity, 
                  RoutingBridgeRouteContext context) {
              if ( indexingEnabled ) {
                  // So that Hibernate Search will correctly delete entities if necessary.
                  // Only useful if you use SearchIndexingPlan for manual indexing,
                  // as the MassIndexer never deletes documents.
                  routes.addRoute();
              }
              else {
                  routes.notIndexed(); 
              }
          }
      }
  }
  ```
- Apply that routing bridge to the entity types you want to control:

  ```java
  @Entity
  @Indexed(routingBinder = @RoutingBinderRef(type = ManualIndexingRoutingBinder.class))
  public class Book {
      // ...
  }
  ```
- The routing bridge will effectively disable automatic indexing.
- To index manually, do this:

  ```java
  ManualIndexingRoutingBinder.withIndexingEnabled(() -> {
      Search.mapping(entityManagerFactory).scope(Book.class)
              .massIndexer()
              .startAndWait();
  });
  ```

I didn't test this exactly, so please report back, but in principle this should work.